# Adverb position <hardly>

Tags: differences, adverbs, negation, negative-polarity-items

I’m asking about the position of the adverb “hardly” in sentences. If the second sentence doesn’t have the same meaning as the first, what’s the difference?

> 1. I had hardly any money coming into the house.
> 2. I hardly had any money coming into the house.

Comment: In this example I think the meaning is the same.

Comment: @Max: Not necessarily. #2 could validly be used in contexts where I had *no money whatsoever* coming in. Just as ***I hardly think so!*** means *I definitely **don't** think so!* (not *I only think that a little bit*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not sure about that.  I think that if you had no money coming in you would say "I had no money coming in", not "I hardly had any money coming in".  At least, that would be the common perception, I think.  This is just my opinion, which is why it's in a comment not an answer.

Comment: @Max: You surprise me. Assuming you accept my ***hardly think so*** example (and, for example, *It's hardly as if I had any money coming in*), at what point do you suddenly decide ***hardly*** can't be used to express ***total*** negation?

Comment: I don't think there's a difference in meaning, but (1) is better because "hardly any" refers to "money". Oh, and you would say "into the house".

Comment: The first sentence was said by Susan Boyle in her interview. I made the second.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Hardly* and *barely* **are negatives**, which is why they block *not* as a duplicate.

Comment: @tchrist: I don't know what you're getting at there. As I think I've demonstrated, ***hardly*** can be used to either negate or minimize - but unless I'm missing something, ***barely*** only ever minimizes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *“I can barely hear you”* is a legal sentence, but the version with *cannot/can’t* is not. That test reveals that *barely* negates, just like *hardly* and *barely*. As Horn recently said, we still don’t know squatᴺᴾᴵ about Negative Polarity Items.

Comment: @tchrist: I think that test simply shows that *barely/hardly* have "negative polarity", meaning that ordinarily (excluding double-negative usages like *I didn't hardly touch him!*) they can't be combined with "100% negating" ***not***. But that doesn't mean that such terms are restricted to partial or complete negation in and of themselves.

Comment: You should cite and add a link to where you saw the first example. You mentioned Susan Boyle in the comments. It would really "lift" the question, and explain why you are asking. Could you also add your thoughts on the 1st example?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps *some people*, at some point, have said "hardly any money" to mean "no money".  Regardless, it's not the common **interpretation** - that is, the large majority of people, on hearing the phrase "hardly any money" would think that it means "a tiny amount of money" rather than "no money".  That's the point I was making.

Comment: @Max: I never suggested anyone would use "adjectival" ***hardly any** money* to mean *no money **at all***. I was simply pointing out that "adverbial" *I **hardly [verb]*** (Sense 2 [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hardly) *- probably or **surely not***) can be used with the "total negation" sense.

Answer (score 2):

"hardly **any**" is a negative counterpart to "only **some**", and the latter is analyzed by McCawley in *The Syntactic Phenomena of English* as an adverb used to compare or contrast its focus, here "**some**".  The placement of "only", and I suppose this "hardly" as well, is governed by the rule that the adverb must be a syntactic modifier of some constituent which contains its focus, but which constituent is modified, when there are several choices, makes no difference to the sense.

So, just as "I had only **some** money coming in" means the same as "I only had **some** money coming in", because in the latter example "only" is attached to the V-bar which contains it's focus "**some**", we'd expect your two examples to mean the same.  In my opinion, they do.

To verify this analysis, we can compare placement of the adverb after and before an indirect object verb (as McCawley does with "only"):

- I gave Mary only **some** money.
  *I gave only Mary **some** money.
   I only gave Mary **some** money.

  I gave Mary hardly **any** money.
  *I gave hardly Mary **any** money.
   I hardly gave Mary **any** money.

As we see, the pattern is the same.

Comment: I agree that *hardly any* indicates negation, and that *only* can also be a negative polarity item. However, the reason that *only Mary* and *hardly Mary* are not equivalent is that *only Mary* makes *only* an adjective equivalent to *Mary alone*, whereas it is difficult to fit *hardly* into a similar adjectival position. “It was hardly Mary who took the candy” might be a counterexample supporting *hardly* as an adjective, but it can also be read as equivalent *certainly not* which could be argued to negate the *was* before it. I don’t know; it’s all a bit fuzzy in my mind — but fascinating.

Comment: @tchrist, you misunderstand the intent of the examples.  Following McCawley, I mark the focus of "only" or "hardly" using boldface, corresponding to emphasis in the pronunciation.  In the ungrammatical example "I gave only Mary **some** money", the bolded "**some**" is the focus, not "Mary".  Whether there is some other construction possible with "**Mary**" as focus of "only" is not relevant to the example.

Comment: Oh I thought you were using the asterisk on the second example to indicate it was not grammatical.

Comment: @tchrist, Yes, I was.  I marked my 2nd and 5th examples as ungrammatical, using asterisks.  I just now in my comment referred to my 2nd example as "the ungrammatical example".  Though I think I've been clear, I guess the underlying difficulty is the fact the linguists are nearly always talking about pronunciations, not conventional spelling/printing.